Abnormal build process termination: ROOT CAUSE: Bad file descriptor on local host ): IntelliJ IDE 2023.2.5
I am using IntelliJ IDE 2023.2.5. I once forcefully killed the IDE and restarted my MacOS, to enable firevault encryption. After this activity I am getting the following error while building any project.
Abnormal build process termination: 
nice -n 10 /Users/kartikrai/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/corretto-17.0.8/Contents/Home/bin/java -Xmx700m -Djava.awt.headless=true "-Djna.boot.library.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/jna/aarch64" -Djna.nosys=true -Djna.noclasspath=true --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.api=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.code=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.comp=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.file=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.main=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.model=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.parser=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.processing=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.jvm=ALL-UNNAMED -Dpreload.project.path=/Users/kartikrai/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.2/demo/IdeaLearningProject "-Dpreload.config.path=/Users/kartikrai/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.2/options" -Dcompile.parallel=false -Drebuild.on.dependency.change=true -Didea.IntToIntBtree.page.size=32768 -Djdt.compiler.useSingleThread=true -Daether.connector.resumeDownloads=false -Dio.netty.initialSeedUniquifier=4495125329093213587 -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.language=en -Duser.country=IN -Didea.paths.selector=IdeaIC2023.2 "-Didea.home.path=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents" "-Didea.config.path=/Users/kartikrai/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.2" "-Didea.plugins.path=/Users/kartikrai/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.2/plugins" -Djps.log.dir=/Users/kartikrai/Library/Logs/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.2/build-log "-Djps.fallback.jdk.home=/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home" -Djps.fallback.jdk.version=17.0.9 -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/Users/kartikrai/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.2/compile-server/idealearningproject_5f1797eb/_temp_ -Djps.backward.ref.index.builder=true -Dtmh.instrument.annotations=true -Dtmh.generate.line.numbers=true "-Djps.kotlin.home=/Users/kartikrai/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.2/plugins/Kotlin/kotlinc" -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation=true -Dkotlin.incremental.compilation.js=true -Dkotlin.daemon.enabled -Dkotlin.daemon.client.alive.path=\"/var/folders/k8/gy5yrg61187_5vhxvj39wcgm0000gp/T/kotlin-idea-11636984239771641885-is-running\" -Dide.propagate.context=false -classpath "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.Launcher "/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/jps-builders-6.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/jps-javac-extension.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/util-8.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/util_rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/platform-loader.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/annotations.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/protobuf.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/jps-model.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/javac2.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/forms_rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/aether-dependency-resolver.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-connector-basic.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-transport-file.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/maven-resolver-transport-http.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar:/Users/kartikrai/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.2/plugins/Kotlin/lib/jps/kotlin-jps-plugin.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/lib/util-8.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/devkit/lib/devkit-runtimeModuleRepository-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/eclipse/lib/eclipse-common.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/ant/lib/ant-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/javaFX/lib/javaFX-common.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/platform-langInjection/lib/java-langInjection-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/Groovy/lib/groovy-constants-rt.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/uiDesigner/lib/jps/java-guiForms-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/space/lib/space-java-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/maven/lib/maven-jps.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/gradle-java/lib/gradle-jps.jar" org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain 127.0.0.1 49207 6f15e7b4-747f-436b-adf3-13f5dbffa104 /Users/kartikrai/Library/Caches/JetBrains/IdeaIC2023.2/compile-server
Be careful, logger will be shut down earlier than application: Unable to make field private static java.util.IdentityHashMap java.lang.ApplicationShutdownHooks.hooks accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @63961c42
Build process started. Classpath: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app/Contents/plugins/java/lib/jps-launcher.jar
Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:49207; reason: Bad file descriptor: /127.0.0.1:49207
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedSocketException: Bad file descriptor: /127.0.0.1:49207
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Bad file descriptor
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:946)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:337)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:776)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:689)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:652)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Exiting.
To address this i have re-installed my IDE comopletely multiple time trying different versions (and used different java versions as well).

Particulary in this line:
 io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedSocketException: Bad file descriptor: /127.0.0.1:49207

We can see the port being not found, which is of the IDE process itself.
I have re-installed the IDE multiple time with different versions and tried running the basic tour project in the IDE with different java versions too, but keep on getting the above error constantly. Please help with the above.
